# Resizing embedded video with nearest-neighbour alg

Tags: javascript, html, css

When embedding a video, no matter if it's flash or by `<video>` tag, when it gets resized, it uses bilinear scaling, so the video looks blurry and bad.

Is there a way to resize the video container using nearest-neighbour algorithm, so it looks sharp?

Tried using this:
http://jsfiddle.net/apx6c4da/

I don't know what's the correct approach to it.

Comment: Yes there is: When resizing it, constrain it using a nearest-neighbour algorithm

Comment: @Jan I don't want to resize the video source (the file itself), that's the point. I want to embed it and resize the container on page, using nearest-neighbour algorithm.

Comment: Yes? Then do that? What have you tried and what is not working? Hang on, aaaah, you mean a setting for the actual video, not constraining the steps at which you choose to resize. No sorry you can't do that. That's up to the rendering software.

Comment: @Jan I tend to ask while I'm researching. I tried using this: http://jsfiddle.net/apx6c4da/

Comment: @Jan I know you can do this with Images, either via CSS or on canvas, so I'm trying to display each frame of embedded video on canvas and resize it using nearest neighbour. Any tips on how can I do this?

Comment: Well, there's the experimental `image-rendering` css attribute, but it doesn't work on video. http://jsfiddle.net/1y5bvr8o/1/ As of now, there's no setting that does what you ask on the video itself.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jan. Maybe that's not exactly what I wanted to do, but it does the same. I can see the stretched video with each frame rendered using nearest-neighbour algorithm! If you would like to post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, there's no setting that does what you ask on the video itself.

For images, there's the [experimental](http://caniuse.com/#search=pixelated) [`image-rendering`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering) css attribute, but it doesn't work on video.

```
image-rendering: pixelated;
```

Here shown on a `canvas` element mirroring the output from a `video` element. The same style is applied to the `video` element but as you can see it does nothing.

https://jsfiddle.net/1y5bvr8o/1

Comment: but it lets us embed the video, set it as hidden, and use canvas to display it nice and clear using nearest-neighbour, which in my opinion is superior to default bilinear or whatever method they use.